# .Net Opposite of GraphicsPath.Widen()

Tags: c#, open-source, graphicspath

I need the opposite of the `GraphicsPath.Widen()` method in .Net:

```
public GraphicsPath Widen()
```

The `Widen()` method does not accept a negative parameter, so I need the equivalent of an `Inset` method:

```
public GraphicsPath Inset()
```

You can do this in the open source Inkscape application (www.Inkscape.org) by going to menu and selecting "Path / Inset" (the Inset amount is stored in the Inkscape Properties dialog).  Since Inkscape is open source, it should be possible to do this in C#.Net, but I can't follow the the Inkscape C++ source for the life of me (and I just need this one function so I can't justify learning C++ to complete this).

Basically, I need a GraphicsPath extension method with this signature:

```
public static GraphicsPath Inset(this GraphicsPath original, float amount)
{
   //implementation
}
```

As the signature states, it will take a `GraphicsPath` object and `.Inset()` the path by a passed amount... just like Inkscape does today.  If it simplifies matters any, the GraphicsPaths in question are all created from the `.PolyBezier` method (and nothing else), so there is no need to account for rects, ellipses, or any other shapes unless you want to do it for completeness.

Unfortunately, I have no experience with C++ code, so its just about impossible for me to follow the C++ logic contained in Inkscape.

.

[EDIT:]
As requested, here is the "MakeOffset" Inkscape code.  The second parameter (double dec) will be negative for an Inset, and the absolute value of that parameter is the amount to bring in the shape.

I know that there are a lot of dependencies here.  If you need to see more of the Inkscape source files, they are here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/inkscape/files/inkscape/0.48/

```
int
Shape::MakeOffset (Shape * a, double dec, JoinType join, double miter, bool do_profile, double cx, double cy, double radius, Geom::Matrix *i2doc)
{
  Reset (0, 0);
  MakeBackData(a->_has_back_data);

    bool done_something = false;

  if (dec == 0)
  {
    _pts = a->_pts;
    if (numberOfPoints() > maxPt)
    {
      maxPt = numberOfPoints();
      if (_has_points_data) {
        pData.resize(maxPt);
        _point_data_initialised = false;
        _bbox_up_to_date = false;
        }
    }

    _aretes = a->_aretes;
    if (numberOfEdges() > maxAr)
    {
      maxAr = numberOfEdges();
      if (_has_edges_data)
    eData.resize(maxAr);
      if (_has_sweep_src_data)
        swsData.resize(maxAr);
      if (_has_sweep_dest_data)
        swdData.resize(maxAr);
      if (_has_raster_data)
        swrData.resize(maxAr);
      if (_has_back_data)
        ebData.resize(maxAr);
    }
    return 0;
  }
  if (a->numberOfPoints() <= 1 || a->numberOfEdges() <= 1 || a->type != shape_polygon)
    return shape_input_err;

  a->SortEdges ();

  a->MakeSweepDestData (true);
  a->MakeSweepSrcData (true);

  for (int i = 0; i < a->numberOfEdges(); i++)
  {
    //              int    stP=a->swsData[i].stPt/*,enP=a->swsData[i].enPt*/;
    int stB = -1, enB = -1;
    if (dec > 0)
    {
      stB = a->CycleNextAt (a->getEdge(i).st, i);
      enB = a->CyclePrevAt (a->getEdge(i).en, i);
    }
    else
    {
      stB = a->CyclePrevAt (a->getEdge(i).st, i);
      enB = a->CycleNextAt (a->getEdge(i).en, i);
    }

    Geom::Point stD, seD, enD;
    double stL, seL, enL;
    stD = a->getEdge(stB).dx;
    seD = a->getEdge(i).dx;
    enD = a->getEdge(enB).dx;

    stL = sqrt (dot(stD,stD));
    seL = sqrt (dot(seD,seD));
    enL = sqrt (dot(enD,enD));
    MiscNormalize (stD);
    MiscNormalize (enD);
    MiscNormalize (seD);

    Geom::Point ptP;
    int stNo, enNo;
    ptP = a->getPoint(a->getEdge(i).st).x;

        double this_dec;
        if (do_profile && i2doc) {
            double alpha = 1;
            double x = (Geom::L2(ptP * (*i2doc) - Geom::Point(cx,cy))/radius);
            if (x > 1) {
                this_dec = 0;
            } else if (x <= 0) {
                this_dec = dec;
            } else {
                this_dec = dec * (0.5 * cos (M_PI * (pow(x, alpha))) + 0.5);
            }
        } else {
            this_dec = dec;
        }

        if (this_dec != 0)
            done_something = true;

    int   usePathID=-1;
    int   usePieceID=0;
    double useT=0.0;
    if ( a->_has_back_data ) {
      if ( a->ebData[i].pathID >= 0 && a->ebData[stB].pathID == a->ebData[i].pathID && a->ebData[stB].pieceID == a->ebData[i].pieceID
           && a->ebData[stB].tEn == a->ebData[i].tSt ) {
        usePathID=a->ebData[i].pathID;
        usePieceID=a->ebData[i].pieceID;
        useT=a->ebData[i].tSt;
      } else {
        usePathID=a->ebData[i].pathID;
        usePieceID=0;
        useT=0;
      }
    }
    if (dec > 0)
    {
      Path::DoRightJoin (this, this_dec, join, ptP, stD, seD, miter, stL, seL,
                         stNo, enNo,usePathID,usePieceID,useT);
      a->swsData[i].stPt = enNo;
      a->swsData[stB].enPt = stNo;
    }
    else
    {
      Path::DoLeftJoin (this, -this_dec, join, ptP, stD, seD, miter, stL, seL,
                        stNo, enNo,usePathID,usePieceID,useT);
      a->swsData[i].stPt = enNo;
      a->swsData[stB].enPt = stNo;
    }
  }

  if (dec < 0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEdges(); i++)
      Inverse (i);
  }

  if ( _has_back_data ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a->numberOfEdges(); i++)
    {
      int nEd=AddEdge (a->swsData[i].stPt, a->swsData[i].enPt);
      ebData[nEd]=a->ebData[i];
    }
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < a->numberOfEdges(); i++)
    {
      AddEdge (a->swsData[i].stPt, a->swsData[i].enPt);
    }
  }

  a->MakeSweepSrcData (false);
  a->MakeSweepDestData (false);

  return (done_something? 0 : shape_nothing_to_do);
}
```

.

**[EDITS]**

**@Simon Mourier** - Amazing work.  The code was even clean and readable!  Nice work, sir.  I did have a couple of questions for you, though.

First, what does a positive number for the Amount represent?  I was thinking that for the Offset method, positive would be "outset" and negative would be "inset", but your example seems to do the opposite.

Second, I did some basic testing (just extending your sample), and found some oddities.

Here is what happens to the "l" in cool when the offset grows (for such a simple letter, it sure likes to cause problems!).

[image: Simon Test 2]

...and the code to reproduce that one:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

            path.AddString("cool", new FontFamily("Arial"), 0, 200, new PointF(), StringFormat.GenericDefault);

            GraphicsPath offset1 = path.Offset(32);

            e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), path);
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), offset1);
    }
```

Finally, something a little different.  Here is the "S" character from Wingdings (appears like a tear drop):

[image: Tear Drop]

Here is the code:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.AddString("S", new FontFamily("Wingdings"), 0, 200, new PointF(), StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        GraphicsPath offset1 = path.Offset(20);

        e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), path);
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), offset1);
    }
```

Man, this is so close, it makes me want to cry.  It still doesn't work, though.

I think what would fix it is to see when the inset vectors intersect, and stop insetting past that point.  If the Inset amount is so large (or the path so small) that there is nothing left, the path should disappear (become null), instead of reversing on itself and re-expanding.

Again, I'm not knocking what you've done in any way, but I was wondering if you know what might be going on with these examples.

(PS - I added the 'this' keyword to make it an extension method, so you might need to call the code using method(parameters) notation to get these samples to run)

.

**@RAN**
Ran come up with a similar output, by re-using the GraphicsPath native methods.  Man, this is tough.  Both of them are so close.

Here is a screen shot of both examples, using the character "S" from Wingdings:

[image: Tear drop comparison]

@Simon is on the left, @Ran on the right.

Here is the same tear drop "S" character after doing an "Inset" in Inkscape.  The Inset is clean:

[image: Tear Inkscape]

By the way, here is the code for @Ran's test:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.AddString("S", new FontFamily("Wingdings"), 0, 200, new PointF(), StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), path);

        GraphicsPath offset1 = path.Shrink(20);
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), offset1);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could post the Inkscape C++ code and someone who knows C++ will be able to help.

Comment: Sure.  I'll post the 'core' function from Inkscape, but there may be quite a few dependencies.

Comment: Do you want this to work on paths in general, or only paths that have previously been widened?  I don't think it will be possible to "undo" a widen transformation and get back the original path, since part of the widen behavior is approximating curves by series of line segments.

Comment: Hi Ben - Great question.  No, these are paths that have not been previously "widened", and no similarity to the .Widen method is required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll still post my new solution, even though it's not perfect, with some list of problems that need to be fixed. Maybe you will want to take parts of it and improve them, or maybe there's some learning value in it.

First of all, the picture - my best inset teardrop symbol:

[image]

**What I've done**

1. I used `GraphicsPath.Widen` to generate the "inner" and "outer" edges of the given figure.
2. I scanned the points of the resulting `GraphicsPath`, to remove the outer edge and keep only the inner one.
3. I flattened the inner edge using `GraphicsPath.Flatten` so that the figures consist only of line segments (no curves).
4. I then scanned all the points on the inner path, and for each current segment:

   4.1. If the current point *p* is outside of the original path, or is too close to a segment on the original path, I calculate a new point, on the current edge, which is in the desired distance from the original path, and I take this point instead of *p*, and connect it to the part I've already scanned.

   4.2. A current limitation in the solution: I continue from the calculated point, to scan onward. This means that there is not good support for shapes with holes (e.g. the Arial "o"). To fix this, one would have to maintain a list of "disconnected" figures, and reconnect figures that have ends at the same point (or ends that are "close enough" to each other).

**The problems**

First I'll specifiy the most major problems and limitations, and then I'll post the code itself.

1. It seems that `GraphicsPath.Widen` does not produce a clean shape. The inner figure that I get has small (but mostly invisible) "jaggedness". The significance of this is that A) my culling algorithm generates more noise, and B) the figure has more points, so performance degrades.
2. Performance is barely acceptable, if at all, at this point. My solution currently scans in a very naive way (in *O(n^n)*) to find line segments that are "too near" the candidate points on the inner edge. This causes the algorithm to be very slow. It can be improved by maintaining some data structure in which segments are sorted by *x*, so that the number of distance calculations is dramatically reduced.
3. I didn't bother to optimize the code to use `structs` and there are a lot of other places the code can be optimized to be much much faster.
4. There is no support for shapes with holes, where the inner figure has to "split" into several figures (like the Arial "o"). I know how to implement it, but it needs more time :)
5. I would consider adapting Simon's approach of moving existing points to get the inner figure, with my approach to clean that path up. (But I couldn't do it at this point because of a bug in Simon's solution, which, for example, causes the pointed end of the Tear symbol to move to a valid location inside the shape. My algorithm thinks this location is valid and doesn't clean it up).

**The code**

I couldn't avoid coming up with some math/geometry utilities of my own.
So here's the code...

Personally, I think this can be worthy of the bounty, even though it's not a perfect solution... :)

```
public class LineSegment
{
    private readonly LineEquation line;
    private RectangleF bindingRectangle;

    public PointF A { get; private set; }
    public PointF B { get; private set; }

    public LineSegment(PointF a, PointF b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;

        line = new LineEquation(a, b);
        bindingRectangle = new RectangleF(
            Math.Min(a.X, b.X), Math.Min(a.Y, b.Y), 
            Math.Abs(a.X - b.X), Math.Abs(a.Y - b.Y));
    }

    public PointF? Intersect(LineSegment other)
    {
        var p = line.Intersect(other.line);
        if (p == null) return null;

        if (bindingRectangle.Contains(p.Value) &&
            other.bindingRectangle.Contains(p.Value))
        {
            return p;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public float Distance(PointF p)
    {
        if (LineEquation.IsBetween(line.GetNormalAt(A), p, line.GetNormalAt(B)))
        {
            return line.Distance(p);
        }
        return Math.Min(Distance(A, p), Distance(B, p));

    }

    static float Distance(PointF p1, PointF p2)
    {
        var x = p1.X - p2.X;
        var y = p1.Y - p2.Y;
        return (float) Math.Sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    }

    public PointF? IntersectAtDistance(LineSegment segmentToCut, float width)
    {
        // always assuming other.A is the farthest end
        var distance = width* (line.IsAboveOrRightOf(segmentToCut.A) ? 1 : -1);
        var parallelLine = line.GetParallelLine(distance);

        var p = parallelLine.Intersect(segmentToCut.line);
        if (p.HasValue)
        {
            if (LineEquation.IsBetween(line.GetNormalAt(A), p.Value, line.GetNormalAt(B)) &&
                segmentToCut.bindingRectangle.Contains(p.Value))
            {
                return p;
            }
        }

        List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
        points.AddRange(segmentToCut.line.Intersect(new CircleEquation(width, A)));
        points.AddRange(segmentToCut.line.Intersect(new CircleEquation(width, B)));

        return GetNearestPoint(segmentToCut.A, points);
    }

    public static PointF GetNearestPoint(PointF p, IEnumerable<PointF> points)
    {
        float minDistance = float.MaxValue;
        PointF nearestPoint = p;
        foreach (var point in points)
        {
            var d = Distance(p, point);
            if (d < minDistance)
            {
                minDistance = d;
                nearestPoint = point;
            }
        }
        return nearestPoint;
    }
}

public class LineEquation
{
    private readonly float a;
    private readonly float b;

    private readonly bool isVertical;
    private readonly float xConstForVertical;

    public LineEquation(float a, float b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        isVertical = false;
    }

    public LineEquation(float xConstant)
    {
        isVertical = true;
        xConstForVertical = xConstant;
    }

    public LineEquation(float a, PointF p)
    {
        this.a = a;
        b = p.Y - a*p.X;
        isVertical = false;
    }

    public LineEquation(PointF p1, PointF p2)
    {
        if (p1.X == p2.X)
        {
            isVertical = true;
            xConstForVertical = p1.X;
            return;
        }

        a = (p1.Y - p2.Y)/(p1.X - p2.X);
        b = p1.Y - a * p1.X;
        isVertical = false;
    }

    public PointF? Intersect(float x)
    {
        if (isVertical)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return new PointF(x, a*x + b);
    }

    public PointF? Intersect(LineEquation other)
    {
        if (isVertical && other.isVertical) return null;
        if (a == other.a) return null;

        if (isVertical) return other.Intersect(xConstForVertical);
        if (other.isVertical) return Intersect(other.xConstForVertical);

        // both have slopes and are not parallel
        var x = (b - other.b) / (other.a - a);
        return Intersect(x);
    }

    public float Distance(PointF p)
    {
        if (isVertical)
        {
            return Math.Abs(p.X - xConstForVertical);
        }
        var p1 = Intersect(0).Value;
        var p2 = Intersect(100).Value;

        var x1 = p.X - p1.X;
        var y1 = p.Y - p1.Y;
        var x2 = p2.X - p1.X;
        var y2 = p2.Y - p1.Y;

        return (float) (Math.Abs(x1*y2 - x2*y1) / Math.Sqrt(x2*x2 + y2*y2));
    }

    public bool IsAboveOrRightOf(PointF p)
    {
        return isVertical ? 
            xConstForVertical > p.X : 
            a*p.X + b > p.Y;
    }

    public static bool IsBetween(LineEquation l1, PointF p, LineEquation l2)
    {
        return l1.IsAboveOrRightOf(p) ^ l2.IsAboveOrRightOf(p);
    }

    public LineEquation GetParallelLine(float distance)
    {
        if (isVertical) return new LineEquation(xConstForVertical + distance);

        var angle = Math.Atan(a);
        float dy = (float) (distance/Math.Sin(angle));
        return new LineEquation(a, b - dy);
    }

    public LineEquation GetNormalAt(PointF p)
    {
        if (isVertical) return new LineEquation(p.X);

        var newA = -1/a;
        var newB = (a + 1/a)*p.X + b;
        return new LineEquation(newA, newB);
    }

    public PointF[] Intersect(CircleEquation circle)
    {
        var cx = circle.Center.X;
        var cy = circle.Center.Y;
        var r = circle.Radius;

        if (isVertical)
        {
            var distance = Math.Abs(cx - xConstForVertical);
            if (distance > r) return new PointF[0];
            if (distance == r) return new[] {new PointF(xConstForVertical, cy) };

            // two intersections
            var dx = cx - xConstForVertical;

            var qe = new QuadraticEquation(
                1,
                -2 * cy,
                r * r - dx * dx);

            return qe.Solve();
        }

        var t = b - cy;
        var q = new QuadraticEquation(
            1 + a*a,
            2*a*t - 2*cx,
            cx*cx + t*t - r*r);

        var solutions = q.Solve();
        for (var i = 0; i < solutions.Length; i++) 
           solutions[i] = Intersect(solutions[i].X).Value;
        return solutions;
    }
}

public class CircleEquation
{
    public float Radius { get; private set; }
    public PointF Center { get; private set; }

    public CircleEquation(float radius, PointF center)
    {
        Radius = radius;
        Center = center;
    }
}

public class QuadraticEquation
{
    public float A { get; private set; }
    public float B { get; private set; }
    public float C { get; private set; }

    public QuadraticEquation(float a, float b, float c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }

    public PointF Intersect(float x)
    {
        return new PointF(x, A*x*x + B*x + C);
    }
    public PointF[] Solve()
    {
        var d = B*B - 4*A*C;
        if (d < 0) return new PointF[0];
        if (d == 0)
        {
            var x = -B / (2*A);
            return new[] { Intersect(x) };
        }

        var sd = Math.Sqrt(d);
        var x1 = (float) ((-B - sd) / (2f*A));
        var x2 = (float) ((-B + sd) / (2*A));
        return new[] { Intersect(x1), Intersect(x2) };
    }
}

public static class GraphicsPathExtension
{
    public static GraphicsPath Shrink(this GraphicsPath originalPath, float width)
    {
        originalPath.CloseAllFigures();
        originalPath.Flatten();
        var parts = originalPath.SplitFigures();
        var shrunkPaths = new List<GraphicsPath>();

        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            using (var widePath = new GraphicsPath(part.PathPoints, part.PathTypes))
            {
                // widen the figure
                widePath.Widen(new Pen(Color.Black, width * 2));

                // pick the inner edge
                var innerEdge = widePath.SplitFigures()[1];
                var fixedPath = CleanPath(innerEdge, part, width);
                if (fixedPath.PointCount > 0)
                    shrunkPaths.Add(fixedPath);
            }
        }

        // build the result
        originalPath.Reset();
        foreach (var p in shrunkPaths)
        {
            originalPath.AddPath(p, false);
        }
        return originalPath;
    }

    public static IList<GraphicsPath> SplitFigures(this GraphicsPath path)
    {
        var paths = new List<GraphicsPath>();
        var position = 0;
        while (position < path.PointCount)
        {
            var figureCount = CountNextFigure(path.PathData, position);

            var points = new PointF[figureCount];
            var types = new byte[figureCount];

            Array.Copy(path.PathPoints, position, points, 0, figureCount);
            Array.Copy(path.PathTypes, position, types, 0, figureCount);
            position += figureCount;

            paths.Add(new GraphicsPath(points, types));
        }
        return paths;
    }

    static int CountNextFigure(PathData data, int position)
    {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = position; i < data.Types.Length; i++)
        {
            count++;
            if (0 != (data.Types[i] & (int)PathPointType.CloseSubpath))
            {
                return count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    static GraphicsPath CleanPath(GraphicsPath innerPath, GraphicsPath originalPath, float width)
    {
        var points = new List<PointF>();
        Region originalRegion = new Region(originalPath);

        // find first valid point
        int firstValidPoint = 0;
        IEnumerable<LineSegment> segs;

        while (IsPointTooClose(
                   innerPath.PathPoints[firstValidPoint], 
                   originalPath, originalRegion, width, out segs))
        {
            firstValidPoint++;
            if (firstValidPoint == innerPath.PointCount) return new GraphicsPath();
        }

        var prevP = innerPath.PathPoints[firstValidPoint];
        points.Add(prevP);

        for (int i = 1; i < innerPath.PointCount; i++)
        {
            var p = innerPath.PathPoints[(firstValidPoint + i) % innerPath.PointCount];

            if (!IsPointTooClose(p, originalPath, originalRegion, width, out segs))
            {
                prevP = p;
                points.Add(p);
                continue;
            }

            var invalidSegment = new LineSegment(prevP, p);

            // found invalid point (too close or external to original figure)
            IEnumerable<PointF> cutPoints = 
                segs.Select(seg => seg.IntersectAtDistance(invalidSegment, width).Value);
            var cutPoint = LineSegment.GetNearestPoint(prevP, cutPoints);

            // now add the cutPoint instead of 'p'.
            points.Add(cutPoint);
            prevP = cutPoint;
        }

        var types = new List<byte>();
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            types.Add(1);
        }
        types.Add(129);

        return points.Count == 0 ?
            new GraphicsPath() :
            new GraphicsPath(points.ToArray(), types.ToArray());
    }

    static bool IsPointTooClose(
        PointF p, GraphicsPath path, Region region, 
        float distance, out IEnumerable<LineSegment> breakingSegments)
    {
        if (!region.IsVisible(p))
        {
            breakingSegments = new LineSegment[0];
            return true;
        }

        var segs = new List<LineSegment>();
        foreach (var seg in GetSegments(path))
        {
            if (seg.Distance(p) < distance)
            {
                segs.Add(seg);
            }
        }
        breakingSegments = segs;
        return segs.Count > 0;
    }

    static public IEnumerable<LineSegment> GetSegments(GraphicsPath path)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < path.PointCount; i++)
        {
            yield return 
                new LineSegment(path.PathPoints[i], path.PathPoints[(i + 1) % path.PointCount]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, when I first posted this as a bounty-less question, I thought it might be relatively simple ("hey, try using the GraphicsPath.Shrink() method), but later realized that it would be more involved than that.  At that point, I put up the bounty and thought that it might be a port of an open-source function.  I later (again) realized that it would be more involved than that.  This is way more than I originally thought I was asking for, and exactly what I need to continue onward.  Thank you for pointing out the 'known' issues, and I will take it from here.  +1 and accepted!  Thanks Ran!

Comment: @FlipScript: Thank! This question was certainly more engaging than I thought it would be when I started working on it, but it was a fun challenge! :)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a nice alternative. It's not as sophisticated as @Simon's, but it gives nice results (that can be further improved), with much simpler code.

The idea is to reuse the existing functionality of `GraphicsPath.Widen` in order to get the points.

When we call `Widen` on a `GraphicsPath` that consists of *n* closed figures, the resulting path has *2n* edges. An outer and an inner edge for each original figure.

So, I create a temporary path, widen it, and copy only the inner edges.

Here's the code:

```
public static GraphicsPath Shrink(this GraphicsPath path, float width)
{
    using (var p = new GraphicsPath())
    {
        p.AddPath(path, false);
        p.CloseAllFigures();
        p.Widen(new Pen(Color.Black, width*2));

        var position = 0;
        var result = new GraphicsPath();
        while (position < p.PointCount)
        {
            // skip outer edge
            position += CountNextFigure(p.PathData, position);
            // count inner edge
            var figureCount = CountNextFigure(p.PathData, position);
            var points = new PointF[figureCount];
            var types = new byte[figureCount];

            Array.Copy(p.PathPoints, position, points, 0, figureCount);
            Array.Copy(p.PathTypes, position, types, 0, figureCount);
            position += figureCount;
            result.AddPath(new GraphicsPath(points, types), false);
        }
        path.Reset();
        path.AddPath(result, false);
        return path;
    }
}

static int CountNextFigure(PathData data, int position)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (var i = position; i < data.Types.Length; i++)
    {
        count++;
        if (0 != (data.Types[i] & (int) PathPointType.CloseSubpath))
        {
            return count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

**And here's an example:**

```
GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
path.AddString("cool", new FontFamily("Times New Roman"), 0, 300, 
    new PointF(), StringFormat.GenericDefault);
e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), path); 
path.Shrink(3);
e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Red), path);
```

Admittedly, my solution also has undesired artifacts when the offset is large enough to cause the shape to intersect with itself.

[image]
**EDIT:**

I can easily detect all the intersection points in O(*n^2*), or with some effort - detect them in O(*n logn*), using a sweep line algorithm (*n* being the number of points).

But once I've found the intersection points, I'm not sure how to decide which parts of the path to remove. Anyone has an idea? :)

**EDIT 2:**

Actually, we don't really need to find intersections of the figures.

What we can do is scan all the points on the figure. Once we found a point that is either outside of the original figure, or is too close to an edge on the original figure, then we have to fix it.

In order to fix a point, we look at the edge between this point and the previous one, and we have to cut this edge so that it will now end in a new point, on the right distance from the original figure.

I've done some experiments with an approximate of this algorithm (with a crude but easy algorithm where I removed the "off" points entirely instead of moving them to shorten their edge, and I checked distances to points on the original figure instead of to edges on it). This got some nice results of removing most of the unwanted artifacts.

To implement the full solution would probably take a few hours...

**EDIT 3:**

Though still far from perfect, I posted my improved solution in a separate answer.

Comment: You da man, Ran.  That's awesome.  Interestingly, it has a similar issue to Simon's, but slightly different.  See my edit on top for what I mean.  If there is a way to 'detect' those intersection points, then just put a point there, and remove the parts that over-run it.  At that point, you will have nailed it!

Comment: @Ran - The Widen use is smart :-) but the problem with this technique lies when mixing points of the Bezier type with others. That's what you can see with oddities in the L and the end of the C here. And that's why my code seems overkill. Can you fix that with Widen? Also, this code does not handle non closed figure - but FlipScript may not need this -:).

Comment: It would be nice if a general use function supported open figures and non-bezier types, but in my specific use scenario, the method will only be used for closed figures composed completely of bezier curves.

Comment: As a side note, in our specific use case performance is not an issue as this will never happen in a loop or while a user waits.  Performance of O(n^2) should be fine, if it comes up with the correct result.

Comment: As far as which parts of the path to remove once you've located the intersection points, I believe that it may be the case that the undesired part of the path will always be closer to the original path than the Offset amount, in some cases even crossing over it.  See your screen shots (and the ones above) for a visual.

Comment: This is excellent, Ran.  I'd love to see you get the last piece in place as a 'tie-breaker' on this one.  Otherwise, I did say that I'd have to give the points to the first working solution, and since this code and Simon's code give essentially the same output, I'm going to have to accept Simon's first answer when the bounty deadline arrives.  However, if this ends up going the full distance, I will accept it as the first fully working solution.  I just wanted to be transparent so there aren't any surprises.

Comment: @FlipScript: that's fair enough. I'll see if I can give it a try sometime tomorrow. BTW: after removing the "bad" parts at the intersections, there will still be a problem with shapes with holes. Do you need to support those? For an example of the problem, draw an "o" in *Times New Roman* and see what happens when the two edges intersect...

Comment: Yes, the shapes may have holes.  In fact, multiple ones.  In the case of the Time New Roman "o": the inset should leave either the shrunken "o", the two crescent shapes on either side, one crescent (if the two sides are not symmetric) or nothing, depending on how large the inset factor is.  Ideally, it should just keep shrinking until its gone.

Comment: @FlipScript: That's tough... I already made some nice progress on removing the "self intersection" artifacts by detecting their distance from the original figure. Now we have to find how to connect detached parts of different figures, in order to create those crescent shapes. Any idea? :)

Comment: @Ran: very nice work +1. I wish I'd join in to contribute somehow but I'm busy with less interesting (much less intersting) computer tasks, good luck with this to you guys

Comment: Sweet!  I can't wait to see the latest... right before the wire, too!

Comment: I was able to remove the "self intersect" artifacts, but right now there are still some bugs which prevent from posting. I doubt I'll have time to fix it before the bounty ends. :)

Comment: @Ran - Update your profile with a web site, twitter account or some other way to reach you.

Comment: @FlipScript: left a message with my email in your web site (through "Contact Us").

Comment: @FlipScript: I posted my imperfect solution afterall. Take a look, see if it's of any value to you :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a code that seems to work. It supports closed & open figures (that's the difficult part...), positive & negative offsets.

Basically, at each point in the path, it computes an Offset point. The offset point is determined using the normal vector, but in fact, it's computed using the intersection of the two offset lines (which is equivalent). There are some cases where it will not be displayed nicely (if path chunks are too close, closer than the offset for example).

Note it does no combine/merge offsets for intersecting figures, but this is another story. A theoretical article can be found here: [An offset algorithm for polyline curves](http://cgcad.thss.tsinghua.edu.cn/~yongjh/papers/CiI2007V58N03P0240.pdf).

You can try it with this example:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

    path.AddString("cool", new FontFamily("Arial"), 0, 200, new PointF(), StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    path.AddEllipse(150, 50, 80, 80);
    path.AddEllipse(150 + 100, 50 + 100, 80 + 100, 80 + 100);

    GraphicsPath offset1 = Offset(path, -5);
    GraphicsPath offset2 = Offset(path, 5);

    e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), path);
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), offset1);
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Blue, 1), offset2);
}
```

The complete code:

```
public static GraphicsPath Offset(GraphicsPath path, float offset)
{
    if (path == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");

    // death from natural causes
    if (path.PointCount < 2)
        throw new ArgumentException(null, "path");

    PointF[] points = new PointF[path.PointCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < path.PointCount; i++)
    {
        PointF current = path.PathPoints[i];
        PointF prev = GetPreviousPoint(path, i);
        PointF next = GetNextPoint(path, i);

        PointF offsetPoint = Offset(prev, current, next, offset);
        points[i] = offsetPoint;
    }

    GraphicsPath newPath = new GraphicsPath(points, path.PathTypes);
    return newPath;
}

// get the closing point for a figure or null if none was found
private static PointF? GetClosingPoint(GraphicsPath path, ref int index)
{
    for (int i = index + 1; i < path.PointCount; i++)
    {
        if (IsClosingPoint(path, i))
        {
            index = i;
            return path.PathPoints[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// get the starting point for a figure or null if none was found
private static PointF? GetStartingPoint(GraphicsPath path, ref int index)
{
    for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (IsStartingPoint(path, i))
        {
            index = i;
            return path.PathPoints[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// get a previous point to compute normal vector at specified index
private static PointF GetPreviousPoint(GraphicsPath path, int index)
{
    if (IsStartingPoint(path, index))
    {
        int closingIndex = index;
        PointF? closing = GetClosingPoint(path, index, ref closingIndex);
        if (closing.HasValue)
        {
            if (closing.Value != path.PathPoints[index])
                return closing.Value;

            return GetPreviousPoint(path, closingIndex);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return path.PathPoints[index - 1];
    }

    // we are on an unclosed end point, emulate a prev point on the same line using next point
    PointF point = path.PathPoints[index];
    PointF next = path.PathPoints[index + 1];
    return VectorF.Add(point, VectorF.Substract(point, next));
}

// get a next point to compute normal vector at specified index
private static PointF GetNextPoint(GraphicsPath path, int index)
{
    if (IsClosingPoint(path, index))
    {
        int startingIndex = index;
        PointF? starting = GetStartingPoint(path, ref startingIndex);
        if (starting.HasValue)
        {
            // some figures (Ellipse) are closed with the same point as the starting point
            // in this case, we need the starting point's next point
            if (starting.Value != path.PathPoints[index])
                return starting.Value;

            return GetNextPoint(path, startingIndex);
        }
    }
    else if ((index != (path.PointCount - 1)) && (!IsStartingPoint(path, index + 1)))
    {
        return path.PathPoints[index + 1];
    }

    // we are on an unclosed end point, emulate a next point on the same line using previous point
    PointF point = path.PathPoints[index];
    PointF prev = path.PathPoints[index - 1];
    return VectorF.Add(point, VectorF.Substract(point, prev));
}

// determine if a point is a closing point
private static bool IsClosingPoint(GraphicsPath path, int index)
{
    return (path.PathTypes[index] & (byte)PathPointType.CloseSubpath) == (byte)PathPointType.CloseSubpath;
}

// determine if a point is a starting point
private static bool IsStartingPoint(GraphicsPath path, int index)
{
    return (path.PathTypes[index] == (byte)PathPointType.Start);
}

// offsets a Point using the normal vector (actually computed using intersection or 90° rotated vectors)
private static PointF Offset(PointF prev, PointF current, PointF next, float offset)
{
    VectorF vnext = VectorF.Substract(next, current);
    vnext = vnext.DegreeRotate(Math.Sign(offset) * 90);
    vnext = vnext.Normalize() * Math.Abs(offset);
    PointF pnext1 = current + vnext;
    PointF pnext2 = next + vnext;

    VectorF vprev = VectorF.Substract(prev, current);
    vprev = vprev.DegreeRotate(-Math.Sign(offset) * 90);
    vprev = vprev.Normalize() * Math.Abs(offset);
    PointF pprev1 = current + vprev;
    PointF pprev2 = prev + vprev;

    PointF ix = VectorF.GetIntersection(pnext1, pnext2, pprev1, pprev2);
    if (ix.IsEmpty)
    {
        // 3 points on the same line, just translate (both vectors are identical)
        ix = current + vnext;
    }
    return ix;
}

// a useful Vector class (does not exists in GDI+, why?)
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct VectorF : IFormattable, IEquatable<VectorF>
{
    private float _x;
    private float _y;

    public VectorF(float x, float y)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }

    public float X
    {
        get
        {
            return _x;
        }
        set
        {
            _x = value;
        }
    }

    public float Y
    {
        get
        {
            return _y;
        }
        set
        {
            _y = value;
        }
    }

    public double Length
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(_x * _x + _y * _y);
        }
    }

    public VectorF Rotate(double angle)
    {
        float cos = (float)Math.Cos(angle);
        float sin = (float)Math.Sin(angle);
        return new VectorF(_x * cos - _y * sin, _x * sin + _y * cos);
    }

    public VectorF DegreeRotate(double angle)
    {
        return Rotate(DegreeToGradiant(angle));
    }

    public static PointF GetIntersection(PointF start1, PointF end1, PointF start2, PointF end2)
    {
        float denominator = ((end1.X - start1.X) * (end2.Y - start2.Y)) - ((end1.Y - start1.Y) * (end2.X - start2.X));
        if (denominator == 0) // parallel
            return PointF.Empty;

        float numerator = ((start1.Y - start2.Y) * (end2.X - start2.X)) - ((start1.X - start2.X) * (end2.Y - start2.Y));
        float r = numerator / denominator;

        PointF result = new PointF();
        result.X = start1.X + (r * (end1.X - start1.X));
        result.Y = start1.Y + (r * (end1.Y - start1.Y));
        return result;
    }

    public static PointF Add(PointF point, VectorF vector)
    {
        return new PointF(point.X + vector._x, point.Y + vector._y);
    }

    public static VectorF Add(VectorF vector1, VectorF vector2)
    {
        return new VectorF(vector1._x + vector2._x, vector1._y + vector2._y);
    }

    public static VectorF Divide(VectorF vector, float scalar)
    {
        return vector * (1.0f / scalar);
    }

    public static VectorF Multiply(float scalar, VectorF vector)
    {
        return new VectorF(vector._x * scalar, vector._y * scalar);
    }

    public static VectorF Multiply(VectorF vector, float scalar)
    {
        return Multiply(scalar, vector);
    }

    public static VectorF operator *(float scalar, VectorF vector)
    {
        return Multiply(scalar, vector);
    }

    public static VectorF operator *(VectorF vector, float scalar)
    {
        return Multiply(scalar, vector);
    }

    public static PointF operator -(PointF point, VectorF vector)
    {
        return Substract(point, vector);
    }

    public static PointF operator +(VectorF vector, PointF point)
    {
        return Add(point, vector);
    }

    public static PointF operator +(PointF point, VectorF vector)
    {
        return Add(point, vector);
    }

    public static VectorF operator +(VectorF vector1, VectorF vector2)
    {
        return Add(vector1, vector2);
    }

    public static VectorF operator /(VectorF vector, float scalar)
    {
        return Divide(vector, scalar);
    }

    public static VectorF Substract(PointF point1, PointF point2)
    {
        return new VectorF(point1.X - point2.X, point1.Y - point2.Y);
    }

    public static PointF Substract(PointF point, VectorF vector)
    {
        return new PointF(point.X - vector._x, point.Y - vector._y);
    }

    public static double AngleBetween(VectorF vector1, VectorF vector2)
    {
        double y = (vector1._x * vector2._y) - (vector2._x * vector1._y);
        double x = (vector1._x * vector2._x) + (vector1._y * vector2._y);
        return Math.Atan2(y, x);
    }

    private static double GradiantToDegree(double angle)
    {
        return (angle * 180) / Math.PI;
    }

    private static double DegreeToGradiant(double angle)
    {
        return (angle * Math.PI) / 180;
    }

    public static double DegreeAngleBetween(VectorF vector1, VectorF vector2)
    {
        return GradiantToDegree(AngleBetween(vector1, vector2));
    }

    public VectorF Normalize()
    {
        if (Length == 0)
            return this;

        VectorF vector = this / (float)Length;
        return vector;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(null, null);
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return string.Format(provider, "{0:" + format + "};{1:" + format + "}", _x, _y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _x.GetHashCode() ^ _y.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if ((obj == null) || !(obj is VectorF))
            return false;

        return Equals(this, (VectorF)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(VectorF value)
    {
        return Equals(this, value);
    }

    public static bool Equals(VectorF vector1, VectorF vector2)
    {
        return (vector1._x.Equals(vector2._x) && vector1._y.Equals(vector2._y));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Simon Mourier: This is it (tested it). Bounty must be awarded as I doubt anything closer would be posted. To our credit though (@FlipScript (suggested circles instead of squares at one point), @Ran & I) we figured out a very approximate design/implementation as this so plus one us:) +1 to you too as I can't do more. Finally, I gotta say that this post is quite nice as it clearly shows that by ourselves we are somewhat "stupid" & limited but together we are smarter & able to figure things which venture into unknown areas. I read somewhere : "Almost any 2 people are smarter than Einstein"

Comment: Wow, Simon!  Amazing.  You came out of nowhere with this.  This looks like it's just about there.  Since I can't post code or images in a comment, I'm going to amend my original query (on top) to add in a couple of comments about your routine.  I'm super impressed, though!  I think we're close...

Comment: @FlipScript - I have updated the code to ensure the oddities you have noticed with the Wingding S is symetric. Better than nothing :-) However, I don't think I can fix this general case easily, if anyone can, I'd be happy to take a look at it. Concerning the COOL case with the I and the C, that's normal, it's because the offset is too big. To over simplify, it's bigger than twice the shapes interior size. As I said, this case is not covered by this simple algorithm.

Comment: @Simon - Thanks for the update.  When the offset is too large, the path size should reduce down to zero, but no further (i.e. not re-expand).  With an Inset, the path should be guaranteed to only get smaller.  With a very large offset, it would be fine if the function returned "null" meaning that the path simply no longer exists, or a single point located where the path disappeared.  Either would be fine.

Comment: @Simon - Thank you so much for this awesome work.  In the end, @Ran took the solution a bit further by removing the path intersections, so his code ends up being a more fully functioning routine.  I wish that I could grant some of the bounty points to you for this great work, but it's "all or nothing" with SO, so I had to grant the points to @Ran.  Thank you so much for your help, though.  I will keep an eye out for you on here and help you out wherever I can.  You've got a friend in me...

Comment: @Simon - For an interesting visual, try the tear drop experiment with an offset of 73.

Comment: @FlipScript - Yes, again, it's very logical as the offset is bigger than the shape. If you want fun, compare latest Ran's code with mine on Wingdings 'e' 200 px character, offset 2 (and compare the perf as well). I think the question is not fully answered :-) Anyway, no offense, I won't work on improving my code since the bounty is now gone :-)

Comment: To anyone coming to this thread late, NONE of these methods work.  They were all close, but this seemingly 'simple' task turned out to be far from simple, and required way, way more thought and code than this.  Thanks for all of your input, though!  It was fun trying.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I think I have a lead for you guys... but its in a completely different direction.

Anyway, I realized that a "sub-path" of a larger path actually shrinks (insets) during a `.Widen` operation, so I decided to see if there was anything fruitful down that path (no pun intended).

Really, the idea here is to `.Widen` the path... from the outside!

What if we took the original `GraphicsPath` and 'wrapped' it in a larger `Rectangle` (doing an `Inflate` of 10 on the `.GetBounds` of the `GraphicsPath` should get us an easy wrapper).

Then, the wrapper is added first, and the real `GraphicsPath` is the added as a sub-path to that.  The entire thing then gets a `.Widen`, and finally, a new `GraphicsPath` is created from scratch, using the `.PathPoints` and `.PathTypes` of the widened path, which removes the useless wrapper (luckily, the `GraphicsPath` accepts `PathPoints` and `PathTypes` in one of the constructor overloads).

I will be out of the office for the rest of the day, so I can't see this through to completion, but here is the lead.

Just drop this code into a regular ol' form:

```
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            GraphicsPath g = new GraphicsPath();
            g.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200));
            g.AddEllipse(50, 50, 100, 100);

            //Original path
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Black,2), g);

            //"Inset" path
            g.Widen(new Pen(Color.Black, 10));
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Red, 2), g);
        }
```

From that simple experiment, you will see that the target path (the circle) now has the elusive Inset (in red)!

[image: Inset Experiment]

There is also has some other crap that I don't really understand in there (which also appears on the rectangle wrapper), but from the `PathPoints` and `PathTypes`, it should be possible to iterate the arrays and remove the junk when the virgin GraphicsPath is created (or find out where that junk comes from and prevent it from happening).  Then return the new, clean `GraphicsPath`.

This technique avoids all of the complex math, but its a bit of a long shot.